# schedule airflow dag trigger on nth business day every month

Tags: cron, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm using airflow 2.0.2. How can I set up the schedule to auto trigger the dag on the 10th business day every month.
I looked up the cron-based schedule, it doesn't seem have this option.

Comment: [Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timetable.html) can be used to make a custom schedule. Or you could run your DAG daily and have the first task check if it's the 10th-weekday using PythonOperator or ShortCircuitOperator.